# BaseInputConnection commitText not sending text to a WebView

Tags: android, webview

I'm developing a simple web browser that has `Button`s on top of a `WebView`. These buttons work as text input shortcuts customizable by the user. Let's say the user types a lot "1234567890", he can set that text in a button shortcut and every time he taps it, the text is sent to the `WebView`. To accomplish this I'm using `BaseInputConnection`.

My problem is that the text is not sent to the `WebView`. But if it's a shortcut for a key press it works.
This is what I have:

```
private WebView wv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_browser);

    wv = findViewById(R.id.wvMain);
    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    ...
   }
...
}

public void onShortcutButtonClick(View view) {
    Shortcut sc = (Shortcut) view.getTag(); // Shortcut is a custom class that holds the type and text of the shortcut among other stuff.
    switch (sc.getType()) {
        case Shortcut.TYPE_KEY: {
            BaseInputConnection inputConnection = new BaseInputConnection(wv, true);
            inputConnection.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0)); // Works! "0" is sent to whatever field the cursor is in the page of the WebView.
        }
        break;
        case Shortcut.TYPE_TEXT: {
            BaseInputConnection inputConnection = new BaseInputConnection(wv, true);
            inputConnection.commitText("1234567890", 0)); // Doesn't work.
        }
        break;
        ...
    }
}
```

sendKeyEvent works but commitText doesn't. I don't know if this is the best way to send text to a `WebView`. I also tried sending the text to the active element of the page using JavaScript but it doesn't work most of the time.